# Why this react app only updates new content if dev-tool is opened?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have a small react app that fetch new content when a button is clicked. for some reason it only updates the state if chrome dev-tool is open. I am using axios to fetch the content. I am pretty sure I'm doing something wrong in there. I have to say that I'm new on React, and trying to learn.

here is my code.

```
class QuoteBox extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
    quotes: '',
    author:'',
    isLoading: false
    }
    this.handleRequest = this.handleRequest.bind(this)
  }

  handleRequest(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({isLoading: true});
    axios.get(`https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&callback="`)
    .then(res => this.setState({
        quotes: res.data[0].content,
        isLoading: false
      })
    );
  }
```

This is the render method

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className='box'>
          <div className="text">
            {parser(this.state.quotes)}
          </div>
          <p className="author">- {this.state.author.toUpperCase()}</p>
          <footer>
            <div className="mediaIcons">
              <i className="fab fa-twitter-square"></i>
              <i className="fab fa-facebook-square"></i>
            </div>
          </footer>
        </div>
        <button className="btn btnQuote" onClick={this.handleRequest}>New Quote</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

If I click the button I only get the first result if dev-tool is closed, and subsequent clicks do not load new data. but if the dev-tool is open, it works fine.

Your help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: hmm this code should work with and without dev tools, why you claim it not working? you cannot see it e.g. `{this.state.author.toUpperCase()}` or  `{parser(this.state.quotes)}` on the page? Because you can e.g. set state properly but displaying it wrongly. btw you do not need to call `e.preventDefault();` while clicking button

Comment: I can't tell why I doesn't work. Btw your constructor is wrong, it should be  ```constructor(props) { super(props); ... }```

Comment: As I stated, it only displays once, if you click again, it displays that same result, if I open dev-tool I can see the fetched data as an Array of object, if I click on the button with the dev-tool opened, the fetched data it displays as an object. I will publish the app so you can check it live, if that is OK with you guys.

Comment: Yes, Ha Ja I removed it to troubleshoot it, will add it back.